# Plone Command not Found when starting plone

Tags: plone

I have just installed plone on debian squeeze without problems. I am trying to start with "plone /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/bin/plonectl start" and I receive Command not found.

Are there any paths I need to export? "which plone" gives me nothing.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the "plone" at the beginning of your command, but you probably do need "sudo".

Try `sudo /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/bin/plonectl start`

Answer (score 3):

Because Plone is a server built with Python, there is no special `plone` command.

Presumably you used the [Plone Unified installer](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/installing-plone/installing-on-linux-unix-bsd/what-is-the-unified-installer), creating a ZEO installation. Because it was installed in `/user/local/Plone` I am also assuming you [installed it as root](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/installing-plone/installing-on-linux-unix-bsd/root-or-user-install).

Information on how to run Plone after installation is found on the [Installation Quick Guide (under "Last steps")](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/installing-plone/installation-quick-guide); you simply run the command `./bin/plonectl start`, or, with your full path: `/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/bin/plonectl start`.

If you are not logged in as root still, you'll need to run that command with `sudo`; the server will automatically switch to the dedicated `plone` user installed by the Unified Installer.